# Mistake in method android-studio

Tags: java, android-studio

*I'm coding at android Studio, the method "secretWord" inside the class generates a mistake, but I don't know why... The method is implemented outside the class "Myclass". Could you help me please

```
package com.example.logic;
public  class Myclass {
    String []xxx={"abc","def","ghi"};
    public MyClass(String[] xxx) {
        this.xxx = xxx;
    }
    secretWord(xxx) ;
}
public  String secretWord(String [] xxx) {
    int index;
    index=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    return xxx[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comments within the code bellows, there are many things you have to modify to make this code works.

```
class Myclass {
        String []xxx={"abc","def","ghi"};
        public Myclass(String[] xxx) { // first, constructor method should have same name with class name
            this.xxx = xxx;
            secretWord(xxx); // second, this statement should be inside a method
        }
        
        public  String secretWord(String [] xxx) { // third, this method should be put inside a class
            int index;
            index=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            return xxx[index];
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

For using in multiple classes, you should seperate method into another class

```
class Myclass {
    String []xxx={"abc","def","ghi"};
    public Myclass(String[] xxx) { // first, constructor method should have same name with class name
        this.xxx = xxx;
        SecretUtil.secretWord(xxx); // second, this statement should be inside a method
    }
}

static class SecretUtil {
    public static String secretWord(String [] xxx) { // third, this method should be put inside a class
        int index;
        index=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
        return xxx[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I have a lot of mistakes. But I need that the method works independently. I mean, I need use that method in other class where I have the interface. For example: Myclass object;   object.secretWord and when I use that I should receive a random String of that method .